# How to call a method defined in one module from another module when they are both included in a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mixins

```
module A
  def before
    puts :before
  end
end

module B
  before
end

class Test
  include A
  include B
end
```

So, the goal is to call `before` as module B is parsed, without using `extend A` within module B.

Ruby 2.5.1

Comment: If you define as `self.before` in `module A` and call `A::before` in `module B` is a valid way for you?

Comment: "as module B is parsed" - at this point, it has no chance of knowing that `before` should be resolved to an `A`. So it's impossible, given current definitions / restrictions.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you're trying to achieve? Maybe there is another way to do this

Comment: You cannot execute code during parsing. Ruby doesn't have parse-time code execution like e.g. Lisp has.

Comment: @LeticiaEsperon - Creating before filters for a Router.

Answer (score 0):

When you `include` a module, that takes the instance methods of the module and imports them as instance methods. However, the way you call the `before` method here, would only work if it was a *class* method.

If you want B to import `before` as a class method, you can do so with `extend`:

```
module B
  extend A
  before
end
```

Without this additional `extend`, you could call `before` from B only in instance method scope, and only if the method on B was called by `Test`:

```
module A
  def before
    puts :before
  end
end

module B
  def call_before
    before
  end
end

class Test
  include A
  include B
  def do_thing
    call_before
  end
end

Test.new.do_thing # => before
```